# Theme Customizer - Text without a setting (a comment or <p> tag)

Tags: theme-customizer

In the Theme Customizer, is it possible to just have text (for example a comment, or a HTML `<p>` tag with text), or a setting that has no type (but a title of `Text I need to display`).

For example, I may want to say - `Go to XXX to do this` at the bottom of a section, or `Find out more in the documentation`

I know you can have descriptions on settings but that is not what I want (unless the setting itself is invisible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, the easiest way to implement this now is to create a new control type that doesn't actually render any input but rather just displays your desired text. Controls have to have an associated setting, so you can register a setting with a custom type of `noop` so that it will not have any effect. Give the control a high priority so it will appear at the end of the section.

A more elegant solution would be to create a custom section that has this end matter as part of its template. Unfortunately, the `ul` is currently expected to be a direct descendent of the section container, so this is problematic.